# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference while getting instance of other class and method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am Working on Android Project , Error i am facing displayed below , i am trying to call prefrenceManager from login activity through MyApplication instance, but i am geting null pointer exception i dont know why , i might not grabbing the getPrefM() but i check all , everything seems to be fine , where i am making a mistake , kindly help me out .

```
01-01 15:32:35.571 32658-32658/com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor/com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.activity.Login_Act}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.helper.MyPrefM com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.app.MyApplication.getPrefM()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.helper.MyPrefM com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.app.MyApplication.getPrefM()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.activity.Login_Act.onCreate(Login_Act.java:54)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Login_Act.java:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.R;
import com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.app.EndPoints;
import com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.app.MyApplication;
import com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.model.User;

public class Login_Act extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = Login_Act.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText inputName, inputEmail;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail;
    private Button btnEnter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





        /**
         * Check for login session. It user is already logged in
         * redirect him to main activity
         * */
        if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefM().getUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main_Act.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);

        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));

        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * logging in user. Will make http post request with name, email
     * as parameters
     */
    private void login() {
        if (!validateName()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validateEmail()) {
            return;
        }

        final String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                EndPoints.LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // check for error flag
                    if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                        // user successfully logged in

                        JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                        User user = new User(userObj.getString("user_id"),
                                userObj.getString("name"),
                                userObj.getString("email"));

                        // storing user in shared preferences
                        MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefM().storeUser(user);

                        // start main activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_Act.class));
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        // login error - simply toast the message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);

                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Validating name
    private boolean validateName() {
        if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(inputName);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Validating email
    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
            requestFocus(inputEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;
        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.input_name:
                    validateName();
                    break;
                case R.id.input_email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApplication.java:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    private MyPrefM pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = MyApplication.this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public MyPrefM getPrefM() {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new MyPrefM(MyApplication.this);
        }

        return pref;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        pref.clear();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login_Act.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**MyPrefM.java:**

```
public class MyPrefM {

    private String TAG = MyPrefM.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "androidhive_gcm";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String KEY_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";

    // Constructor
    public MyPrefM(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void storeUser(User user) {
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_ID, user.getId());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        editor.putString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        editor.commit();

        Log.e(TAG, "User is stored in shared preferences. " + user.getName() + ", " + user.getEmail());
    }

    public User getUser() {
        if (pref.getString(KEY_USER_ID, null) != null) {
            String id, name, email;
            id = pref.getString(KEY_USER_ID, null);
            name = pref.getString(KEY_USER_NAME, null);
            email = pref.getString(KEY_USER_EMAIL, null);

            User user = new User(id, name, email);
            return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addNotification(String notification) {

        // get old notifications
        String oldNotifications = getNotifications();

        if (oldNotifications != null) {
            oldNotifications += "|" + notification;
        } else {
            oldNotifications = notification;
        }

        editor.putString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, oldNotifications);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getNotifications() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, null);
    }

    public void clear() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `MyApplication.getInstance()` returned null

Comment: i think `MyApplication.getInstance()` is `null` - have you done debugging and checked the variables

Comment: it doesnot suppose to return null , how should i fix this .?

Comment: yes , its null in Login_Act activity in Oncreate method , the first if statement

Comment: i have no idea why it is returning null

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your MyApplication class.

Comment: MyApplication class is mentioned check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnCreate` method from the `MyApplication` is not called before the activity is created. To solve this problem you should add the `MyApplication` to the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
</application>
```

So the `MyApplication` `onCreate` method is called before any activity is created.

> Base class for maintaining global application state. You can provide
>   your own implementation by creating a subclass and specifying the
>   fully-qualified name of this subclass as the *"android:name"* attribute
>   in your **AndroidManifest.xml's**  tag. The Application
>   class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated
>   before any other class when the process for your application/package
>   is created.

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefM().getUser() != null) in this line i am getting null pointer axception , and it is in login class

Comment: where should i try the above code ? in login class?

Comment: mInstance = MyApplication.this; cannot assign this .. it says remove static reference , mInstance can only be assigned in onCreate Method, and then can be returned , previously doned this , but null pointer exception arises

Comment: any solution for this problem ?

Comment: no i am following a tutorial and trying to buiild something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132005/discussion-between-kevin-wallis-and-addi-star).

Comment: Saved . thanx this class extends application and must provide reference in manifest , which i forgot to put , working now thanx :-)